# A question on relationship between expansion of a function and 'integral'.

Tags: analysis

I am reviewing fundamental analysis these days. After finishing the part of integral, I came up with a question I had, but finally forgot long ago. 
The Taylor expansion of a function gives an 'approximation' of a function near a specific point, up to higher 'infinitsimal' of some polynomial. And the derivative function is only a member of such approximations①, in which case the degree of such polynomial is of order 1.
Here's my rather vague question: we can see that the derivative itself can 'restore' the original function by simply integraling it. But the derivative function gives actually little information comparing with other members in the family of approximation polynomials as above(①). Is there anything more that other members of ① can do (with similar operations like integral), while the derivative function cannot?\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Taylor approximations' definition a-priori only include information about the function's derivatives' in a given point. Not everywhere!

If the function is a so called real-analytic function (Taylor approximations converge to the function), then you can fully recover the function from information about its derivatives in one point. This is a very powerful property, as you only need to know the function on a tiny interval $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ to recover the function everywhere, even outside of this tiny interval.

However, if you know the first derivative everywhere, and also the function's value in at least one point, then you can recover the whole function everywhere by integrating. Note that this works always, whereas the above process of recovering the function everywhere via Taylor only works in certain cases (if the function is real-analytic).

So the best you can hope for is that all the derivatives in one point, will include the same amount of information as the first derivative everywhere (case of real-analyticity). However, in general, the first derivative everywhere includes more information (no real-analyticity).

Comment: Integrating need the value of derivative almost everywhere, and if this is what we have, derivative of up to the highest order of the original function can be described. Therefore whenever integrating can be done, approximation near any point can be done. Thanks a lot. I'm alway being trapped in some questions like dream-talk :(